# codeigniter how to send query->num_rows from model to controller to view

Tags: php

I'm new in codeigniter, I'm having a challenge with num_rows on view page
Here's the sample of the code - **Updated**
Model

```
 public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}

public function total_referred_in()
{


    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM daily_out_patient');

    return $query->num_rows();

}
```

Controller

```
 public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $this->load->model('Referrals_form_model', 'referral'); /* LOADING MODEL * Referral_form_model as referral */
}


public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('referrals_form_view');
}

public function referral_in()
{
    $data['total_referred_in'] = $this->load->referral->total_referred_in(); //get referral data
    $this->load->view("referral_form_view", $data);
}
```

}

View

```
<span><?php
    echo $query->num_rows();

?></span>
```

when i run the code, it tell me undefined variable "query"

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code as below.

MODEL:

```
 public function total_referred_in()
 {
   $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM daily_out_patient');
   return $query->num_rows();
 }
```

Controller

```
public function referral_in()
{
   $data['total_referred_in'] = $this->load->referral->total_referred_in(); //get referral data
   $this->load->view("referral_form_view", $data);
}
```

View :

```
<span>
   <?php
   echo $total_referred_in;
   ?>
</span>
```

As you can see in Controller line :

```
$this->load->view("referral_form_view", $data);
```

$data here is the data array you are passing to your view. In your view you can access data in $data variable by using $data variable's KEY as php variable(In our case its "total_referred_in").

Comment: Thanks, but displays "Message: Undefined variable: total_referred_in"

Comment: How can i define the variable in my view page?

Comment: Where is your view file referral_form_view.php placed in codeigniter?

Comment: For you to print $total_referred_in in your view using above code, your view template file have to be placed in "application/views/referral_form_view.php"

Comment: Thanks, referral_form_view is placed in "application/views/" folder, but im still getting the same error

Comment: Just for debug, in your controller assign $data['total_referred_in'] = 'TEST'; and then check. Also if possible please share whole code of your Model and controller.

Comment: Please update this code in your question as an Edit. :)

Comment: what is the url you are calling? I think right now you are calling index() function instead of referral_in(). That's why you are getting that error.

Comment: The thing is that, i want the num_rows to display on the index page

Comment: so, just add the code you have added in referral_in() function to index() function. And please refer the Codeigniter docs...i have already shared the link of a basic MVC example. :)

Comment: Still given error, but i appreciate your contribution and time. Thanks

Comment: you can share your zipped code in gdrive with me, i can look at it latter.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't [returning](http://php.net/return) anything from your function, you're just echoing. Try this:

```
public function total_referred_in()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM daily_out_patient');

    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function referral_in()
{

    $data['num_rows'] = $this->load->referral->total_referred_in(); //get referral data
    $this->load->view("referral_form_view", $data);
}
```

And then in your view:

```
<span><?=$num_rows?></span>
```

Comment: I just tried that, but an error message display "undefined variable : query"

Comment: Not familiar with this framework, but seems like anything you pass in to the `view()` function should be available. Try with my updates.